# горизонтальный скролл на всех разрешениях

Tags: html, css

Подскажите знающие товарищи, из-за чего горизонтальный скролл, уже всю голову сломал, не пойму. 
[Ссылка на сайт](http://test.aleksandernitchenko.ru/)

Comment: Не вижу горизонтального скролла

Comment: на мозиле нету, на хроме есть

Comment: я на хроме смотрел - тоже нету, попробуйте кеш почистить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Горизонтальный скролл появляется, если какие-либо элементы занимают ширину, которая больше ширины экрана.

Через инструменты веб-разработчика начните уменьшать ширину экрана до момента, пока не появится скролл. Как только он появился пройдитесь по всем основным элементам и смотрите, не выходят ли они за основную область экрана. И уже непосредственно с этим элементом работайте (прописывайте стили, чтобы элемент не уходил за область экрана).

Так же попробуйте применить этот мета тег в **header:**

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: В том то и дело что в хроме скролл на всех разрешениях, в мозиле такого нет, на мобильных тоже скролл есть. И менее 380px справа дополнительно появляется полоса за пределами html

Comment: какую версию хрома ты используешь?

Comment: Версия 67.0.3396.99 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит) и не только у меня скролл заметен, у многих спрашивал. У кого-то есть у кого-то нет, но на хроме у всех есть

Comment: попробуй сейчас закомментировать следующий блок:
`<div class="categories__menu d-block d-md-none"></div>`
и после этого проверь, остается ли скролл

Comment: хотел еще отписать по поводу свойства **overflow-x** для **body**, но оно уже задано.
в том блоке, про который я отписал тебе выше, содержится выпадающее меню. на разрешении **320px** оно занимает **376px**, поэтому оно сдвигает другие элементы и появляется такой оступ.
еще раз по поводу скролла, оно же не должно появляться, так как задано **overflow-x**, странно это.

Comment: после удаления блока **categories__menu d-block d-md-none** полоса справа исчезает но скролл остается на всех разрешениях. вот этого я не могу понять. +Ширина **body** равна ширине окна (+0,2px), но из-за скрола складывается ощущение что ширина окна меньше чем написано

Comment: попробуй пропиши в стилях это: **html, body {overflow-x: hidden !important;}**

Comment: сделал, скролл остался

Comment: а насколько длинный скролл?

Comment: [gif'ka](http://test.aleksandernitchenko.ru/2.gif) увидеть можно по ссылке

Comment: а теперь попробуй изменить мета тег на этот `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79924/discussion-between--and--).